# Subclassing UICollectionViewLayout and assign to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];    
   // assign layout (subclassed below)
   self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[CustomCollectionLayout alloc] init];
}

// data source is working, here's what matters:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ThumbCell *cell = (ThumbCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ThumbCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   return cell;
}
```

I also have a UICollectionViewLayout subclass: CustomCollectionLayout.m

```
#pragma mark - Overriden methods
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(320, 480);
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // configure CellAttributes
    cellAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // random position
    int xRand = arc4random() % 320;
    int yRand = arc4random() % 460;
    cellAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(xRand, yRand, 150, 170);

    return cellAttributes;
}
```

I'm trying to use a new frame for the cell, just one at a random position. 
The problem is layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath is not called.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find a custom implementation sample for UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: You can look at my Pinterest-inspired UICollectionViewLayout at https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo

Comment: Really interesting Jay ... thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** I didn't notice that you've solved your case, but I had the same problem and here's what helped in my case. I'm leaving it here, it may be useful for someone given that there's not much on this topic yet.

Upon drawing, `UICollectionView` does not call the method `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` but `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` to determine which cells should be visible. It's your responsibility to implement this method and from there call `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` for all visible index paths to determine exact locations.

In other words, add this to your layout:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:16];
    // Determine visible index paths
    for(???) {
        [array addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:??? inSection:???]]];
    }
    return [array copy];
}
```

Comment: If `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` isn't called by the drawing code in `UICollectionViewLayout`, then why is it in the class's interface?!

Comment: Tradition? Older API? Planned API? Suggesting a good pattern? Good question!

Comment: `return [array copy];` is a memory leak (it creates a new instance that is not autorelease), unless you have ARC enabled. Regardless of ARC, it's totally unnecessary and only wastes memory and CPU time. Just return `array`, which is autorelease and a mutable array may always be used in place of an immutable one (as long as it is not mutated after that which would be impossible after return)

Comment: This is the pattern used in most of the sources I've read at a time that answer was posted. My understanding was that it's used to actually **save** memory, as `NSArray` doesn't require all the enhanced internal structure of `NSMutableArray`. For modern mobile devices CPU is considered cheap, while memory is not, so it's highly recommended to perform a small additional calculation if it allows you to free some memory structure afterwards. Also, copying even a considerable array is **way** cheaper than redrawing the layout, so the CPU used for this task is irrelevant.

Comment: Of course, using ARC is assumed. You usually don't disable it in your applications unless you've got a really good reason (and I cannot think of any example of such).

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue with Storyboard parameters. Assigned custom UICollectionLayout from Inspector panel.[image]

Comment: I copy your code and run it. Like you said, `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is not called. But after changing the layout Class in storyboard, the problem remains. Are you sure your code posted here are identical to what you actually use?

Comment: I never said that code posted above is a working code. It was just a spot on how I was assigning the CustomLayout to UICollectionView. For a good working code, I suggest you to look a the link posted by Jay Slupesky ... it helped me a lot.

Comment: You accept your own answer which don't fix the code in the question. That looks very misleading.

Comment: The question is on how to perform a task and not on how to build a working piece of an iOS app. You've probably misunderstood.