# How to set the position of cells on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have an UIViewController which contains a UICollectionView. But the UICollectionView does not fill all the UIViewController.

I find that there is space whose height equals the height of NavigationBar between the cell and the top edge of the UICollectionView. I don't know how I can set the cell position to (0,0) in the UICollectionView. (like this, the space is in the red rectangle)

[image]

I found this link [How do I set the position of a UICollectionViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959637/how-do-i-set-the-position-of-a-uicollectionviewcell/17959755#17959755) And I subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout (the following are my code)

**MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end
```

**MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout.m**

```
#import "MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"

@implementation MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    return [super collectionViewContentSize];
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath");
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) // or whatever specific item you're trying to override
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100); // or whatever...
        return layoutAttributes;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

@end
```

and using it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // hide the tool bar
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    // set title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"User Album";

    [self.userAlbumView setCollectionViewLayout:[[MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]];
}
```

But it does not work. The log *NSLog(@"MZMCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath");* doesn't show. And the blank is still there.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I find this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040542/subclassing-uicollectionviewlayout-and-assign-to-uicollectionview) which answers my question **layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: does not work find**. But the space between cell and the top edge is still there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView adds top margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411442/uicollectionview-adds-top-margin)

Comment: related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916006/in-a-uicollectionview-the-cells-will-not-sit-on-the-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer myself question.

I printed every UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute information in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: and found what I need is to change the frame.orgin.y

following is my code:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[attributes count]];

    for (int i=0; i< [attributes count]; i++) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)[attributes objectAtIndex:i];

        // the key code "attr.frame.origin.y - 63"
        [attr setFrame:CGRectMake(attr.frame.origin.x, attr.frame.origin.y - 63, attr.bounds.size.width, attr.bounds.size.height)];

        //NSLog(@"attr h=%f w=%f x=%f y=%f", attr.bounds.size.height, attr.bounds.size.width, attr.frame.origin.x, attr.frame.origin.y);

        [result addObject:attr];

    }

    return result;
}
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 17):

FYI, this is answered more correctly here: [UICollectionView adds top margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411442/uicollectionview-adds-top-margin)

The problem is the view controller is automatically adjusting scroll view insets.  That can be turned off either in code or IB.  In code just set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21112952/211292) for how to set this with IB.